# R:as.numeric using grep()

Tags: r

quick question.
I have a table (Data) with a series of columns having similar colnames
`colnames(Data)`:

```
[Sum_Flag_x_30,Sum_Flag_y_60,...Sum_Flag_z_n].
```

I ideally want to write a simple code to get all of these into numeric format (as.numeric).
Tried with:

```
Data[,grep("Sum_Flag",colnames(Data),value=T)] <- as.numeric(Data[,grep("Sum_Flag",colnames(Data),value=T)]
```

but it's not working and I get the following error:

> Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , grep("Sum_Flag", colnames(Data),
> :    Supplied 25 items to be assigned to 55057 items of column
> 'Sum_Flag_x_30'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to
> make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Any clue about this?

Thanks guys
Ciao

Comment: Your question is unclear.. Do you want to rename the colnames and then change that to numeric? As in, "Sum_Flag_x_30" would become "30"?

Comment: Hi,sorry. I don't want to rename the columns, just want to trasform the class of the data in these columns into numeric (as.numeric(Data$var)), since they are originally imported as chr.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use `apply`. Apply `as.numeric()` to every column, by doing:

```
# margin = 2 means that you're applying a function column-wise.
new_data <- apply(Data, MARGIN = 2, as.numeric)
```